# Cannot mutate var in an object in scala?

Tags: scala, object, immutability, var, mutation

One of my coworkers showed me an interesting snippet where a var declared within an object was not being mutated by a member of the object. It will be great if somebody explains why is it behaving this way. The code is as follows:

```
object SomeObject{
  var count = 1
  def addToCount = count + 1
  def printCurrentCount:Unit = {addToCount;println(count)}
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined module SomeObject

scala> SomeObject.printCurrentCount
1
```

Shouldn't `printCurrentCount` print out the mutated var count to be 2?

Comment: I'm curious why you think it does what you think it does.  Is it a kind of optical illusion? And if it did do what you imagined, wouldn't printCurrentCount be called printNextCount?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `addToCount` does not add 1 (or anything) to count. It calculates `count + 1`. (Same as Java would...)

I suppose you meant this:

```
...
def addToCount { count += 1 }
...
```

Comment: Totally overlooked the lack of assignment. Thanks